# Downgrading sfdx-cli

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I'm wondering whether it's possible to downgrade sfdx-cli to use an earlier version?  I'm trying to debug an issue with using it in pipeline scripts.  When I run `sfdx version --core` I get `sfdx-cli 7.28.7 (core)` .

If I run 
`sfdx version` I get  `sfdx-cli/7.28.7-7bceba6f24 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3` .

If I do `cat package.json` inside the actual package dir for sfdx-cli after doing `npm install sfdx-cli@7.26.0` I get  `"sfdx-cli": "^7.26.0"`

Why does it then show that the version is 7.28.7?  How can I force the lower version to have preference?  I do understand that this question is not really salesforce specific but hopefully someone has run into the same problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Updated answer (thanks to Shane McLaughlin's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/355264), please upvote their answer as well):

It depends how you installed the CLI originally.  If you installed via npm, lie `npm install -g sfdx-cli` then you can use npm to install whatever version you like, ex: `npm install -g sfdx-cli@7.109.0`

If you installed via the installer (downloading a tarball, pkg, windows installer, etc) then you don't have an easy downgrade path without [uninstalling the CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm) first (it's not hard, it won't lose all your orgs).

Then you can [install an older version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_olderversions) (and turn off auto-update if you want to stay on the older version).

---

### Original Answer (outdated)

You can change to any version you want by using the @version notation:

```
sfdx plugins:install sfdx-cli@7.26.0
```

(Or any other version).

Note that ordinarily there is some "gap" between the various version parts, and is not likely the issue. Normally, you'd upgrade/downgrade the entire salesforcedx package:

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
```

Or

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@46.16.0
```

---

As a quick fix, I recommend:

```
sfdx update
sfdx plugins:update
```

This should ensure that all plugins are up to date.

Alternatively:

```
sfdx salesforcedx@latest
```

---

Also, you might be having some conflicts because, apparently, you wouldn't normally have both `sfdx-cli` and `salesforcedx` installed at the same time (you should be using the latter). DX works just fine on my computer without `sfdx-cli` installed. Here's what my config looks like, for reference:

```
$ sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 2.1.6 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.2 (core)
analytics 1.1.2 (core)
generator 1.1.0 (core)
mo-dx-plugin 0.2.5
salesforcedx 46.16.0
├─ force-language-services 46.23.0
└─ salesforce-alm 46.21.0
```

Comment: salesforcedx seems to follow a API version notation while sfdx-cli doesn't.  If one supersedes the other what is the point of having both?  Is there any?
We have sfdx-cli installed because we are using a custom plugin to build scratch orgs and push code to them.

Comment: @akarnid Looking at the "npm" repo, it appears that `salesforcedx` and `sfdx-cli` are both the same thing. Having both installed sounds like it would probably muck things up. Consider using one or the other, but not both. I think the default installer uses `salesforcedx`, so you don't need the other. I tried installing `sfdx-cli` and it just hung the process.

Comment: I'm marking the answer as valuable.  This convo may help others that stumble onto this in the future :)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I tried downgrading my sfdx-cli to 7.26, but this broke VS Code. sfdx still worked from the commandline, but it was still on the latest version. To address this I had to completely uninstall. Strange.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore. the cmd `sfdx plugins:install sfdx-cli@downgrade-version` succeeds, but then a quick check via `sfdx plugins --core` shows the version i had (and not the downgraded one). just FYI.

Answer (score 12):

**The accepted answer is not correct.**

It depends how you installed the CLI originally.  If you installed via npm, lie `npm install -g sfdx-cli` then you can use npm to install whatever version you like, ex: `npm install -g sfdx-cli@7.109.0`

If you installed via the installer (downloading a tarball, pkg, windows installer, etc) then you don't have an easy downgrade path without [uninstalling the CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm) first (it's not hard, it won't lose all your orgs).

Then you can [install an older version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_olderversions) (and turn off auto-update if you want to stay on the older version).

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to downgrade sfdx cli and the solution proposed above did not work:

`sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@<version>`

It appeared to, but then didn't really change anything. However, [this blog post](https://sunilkhuwal.wordpress.com/salesforce-sfdx-installation/) presented an answer that worked for me.

`npm install sfdx-cli@<version> --global`

replace  with the version number you need.

After you have downgraded sfdx-cli to upgrade back to the latest version of sfdx-cli you will need to first uninstall using the npm command:

`npm uninstall sfdx-cli`

Then reinstall sfdx using the [latest version available](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)

Comment: thanks.  sfdx:force:deploy was not working with latest release so downgraded to 100. Can you tell you what kind of issue you were facing?

Comment: @ManjotSingh, I was having trouble with creating 2gp packages. I was getting the error  "package.xml: No package.xml found" and was advised to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install sfdx-cli@<version> –global
```

did not work for me.

```
npm install -g sfdx-cli@<version>
```

worked. Replace the version number as per your need.