# How to install specific version of sfdx plugin?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

If I'm currently on `salesforcedx 47.15.0` as shown from `sfdx plugins --core`, is there a way to install/update the `salesforcedx` plugin to version `47.09.0`?

I originally installed the `sfdx-cli` from the `.pkg` file from the [developer site](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli).

Would it be possible via `npm`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thought this sounded familiar, and I was able to find a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282941/downgrading-sfdx-cli) that might help you.

Comment: You are a godsend @Derek F! I knew there was a better way!