# package:version:create - No such column 'Id' on entity 'User'

Tags: package, sfdx-error

Suddenly our build is failing due to the `package:version:create` command. The error is really strange since none of our changes look to be related to it.

Our CircleCI automation tool is able to push all the sources into a scratch org and run all the tests with success. But when running the `force:package:version:create`, we now receive the following error:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  No such column 'Id' on
> entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
> append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
> WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Does it ring a bell to someone ? The slightest lead would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm hitting the same, even with `sfdx force:package:list` ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_view_pkg_details.htm)). Just in case, I did an `sfdx update` but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I can see with detailed logs that right before there is an issue with 'The config file: /root/.sfdx/sfdx-project.json is not schema valid Due to: Validation errors: should have required property 'packageDirectories'". Not really sure if it's the root cause of the issue...

Comment: Now that's really interesting. Maybe I messed up some changes in the sfdx-project.json file...

Comment: Actually might be a known issue after latest update of sfdx 7.130.1:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1321

Answer (score 0):

After following the suggestion of downgrading sfdx cli version (github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1321 ), the commands pass and the build was successful. Will upgrade again once SF releases a fix.

Comment: could you please mention which version can we downgrade to? We are also running into the same issue.

Comment: 7.120.0 seems to be safe, please consult: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1321 . Regarding the downgrade itself: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282941/downgrading-sfdx-cli @bonish-koirala