# SFDX CLI: apex tests execution is failing with Time out error. Increasing wait parameter doesn't help

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

I am executing a SFDX CLI command to run apex tests

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -l RunLocalTests --loglevel=trace -y -c -r json -d ./tests/apex -w 20
```

but it fails with a Timeout error. Even when I tried to increase the `-wait` parameter like this

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -l RunLocalTests --loglevel=trace -y -c -r json -d ./tests/apex -w 999999
```

it still fails with the same error:

```
echo $(sfdx force:apex:test:run -l RunLocalTests --loglevel=trace -y -c -r json -d ./tests/apex -w 999999) > tests.json
WARNING: WARNING: In the Summer ’21 release, we'll rename or remove some of the output files that are created when you run force:apex:test:run or force:apex:test:report with the --outputdir (-d) parameter.  This breaking change could impact your CI/CD scripts if they reference specific filenames. See https://sfdc.co/apex-test-updates for details

CLIError: timed out
    at Object.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/index.js:28:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:25:66
    at async flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:124:9) {
  oclif: { exit: 2 },
  code: undefined
}
ERROR running force:apex:test:run:  Unknown error in Apex Library: timed out
```

Does anyone know why this is happenning and if there is any solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-apex/issues/316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Salesforce product team is aware of this error scenario and has filed an issue on [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-apex/issues/316) and internal Investigation `#W-12446679`.Please consider adding repro details on the Git issue.

According to this, the 7.185 release of the CLI is the first one to have the updated version of the apex-node library (v 1.6)

You could use CLI version 7.184 as a workaround.

---

The issue has been fixed. The update should be included in the CLI latest release candidate, which is 7.186.2 as mentioned in [Github link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-apex/issues/316).

Comment: do you we need to downgrade? I have included fetch of the latest SFDX CLI version

Comment: Does the approach in [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282941/downgrading-sfdx-cli) help?

Comment: should I try to run `npm install -g sfdx-cli@7.184.0` instead of npm install -g sfdx-cli`? I haven't tried yet